# URL rewrite before template_redirect called

Tags: url-rewriting, templates, wp-redirect

**Logic**

- I have a page template at `/blog` that contains a "public" blog.
- I have a page template at `/members` that is members area.

If a user enters the URL `/members/blog` I want to catch this in the `template_redirect` hook and load up a custom template that shows a "private" blog

**Problem**

Before `template_redirect` is called `/members/blog` is re-written to `/blog` so I can't load the private blog page.

There is nothing in the rewrite rules that says to do this.

Comment: is `/members/blog` a page?

Comment: No. I wrote this code a while ago so it's not best practice. But I normally catch it in template_direct and do a php include and turn 404 error off

Comment: What's happening is that whenever WordPress encounters a 404, it tries to query for something close. You can see it in this function [`redirect_guess_404_permalink`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/canonical.php#L528). It finds your blog page and redirects there. The simplest solution is to just add a page so it doesn't 404.

Comment: Cheers @Milo that's what I needed to know :) I guess the hacky solution would be to hook into that and stop it guessing if URL begins with /members/blog

Comment: If you wanted to do that, I think conditionally disabling `redirect_canonical` is what you'd need to do. If you search around for that you might find something. The action is added in `wp-includes/default-filters.php`.

Comment: Thanks @Milo for your help, I've posted how I fixed below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was `redirect_guess_404_permalink` was detecting a 404 error and 'guessed' `/members/blog` to be `/blog`

My hacky solution was to hook into the status error check ([Stop Wordpress from "guessing" redirects for nonexistent URLs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28045/stop-wordpress-from-guessing-redirects-for-nonexistent-urls)) and if URL parts match then unset the guessed solution

```
function blog_no_redirect_guess_404_permalink( $header ){
    global $wp_query;

    if( is_404() ) {
        // Get Request URL Parts
        $url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $path = explode('/', $url['path']);
        $path = array_filter($path);
        $path = array_merge($path, array());
        // If matches /members/blog then unset 'guess'
        if (strtolower($path[0]) == 'members' && strtolower($path[1]) == 'blog') {
            unset( $wp_query->query_vars['name'] );
        }
    }

    return $header;
}
add_filter( 'status_header', 'blog_no_redirect_guess_404_permalink' );
```

Comment: I had the same issue, but found what I needed to do was simply give a lower priority to my template_redirect action.