# WordPress Custom Post Type is Matching on Partial Slug

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, redirect

I'm having a really weird issue. For example, there is a custom post 'people'. The post title is the name of the person and pretty permalinks are enabled. Say we have a person custom post with the name of 'John Smith' with a slug of 'john-smith'. If I visit the URL `example.com/jo`, it still redirects me to the URL `example.com/john-smith`.

I've never seen this behaviour in WordPress before. Does anyone know what might be causing it?

Comment: Possibly: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_guess_404_permalink

Comment: Have you tried saving / re-saving the permalinks preferences page so the redirects are re-generated?

Comment: For me WP has worked this way as long as I can remember (well, for real at least a year or two now). So domain.com/xxx... redirects to post for what xxx... is closest for.

edit: If you had a page which url would be example.com/jo I don't think it would redirect you anywhere though... I don't see what's the problem here..

Comment: @jimihenrik - I've got quite a few sites on WP and none of them ever seem to redirect based on a partial match of the slug (just tried it now). This is issue is happening on a site built by somebody else.

Comment: @jimihenrik - Actually just noticed this happens on one of my sites, but only on a custom post. It doesn't happen on a different site, even if the URL is only off by one character. Very weird.

Comment: Oh, strange. Well I don't have a clue what's doing it then... :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your active theme's functions.php file and it should stop Wordpress guessing the source of the incomplete slug:

```
function no_redirect_guess_404_permalink( $header ){
    global $wp_query;

    if( is_404() )
        unset( $wp_query->query_vars['name'] );

    return $header;
}

add_filter( 'status_header', 'no_redirect_guess_404_permalink' );
```

[Original answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28045/stop-wordpress-from-guessing-redirects-for-nonexistent-urls)