# Prevent wordpress autoredirect

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I've got a problem. My client has taken ads with ex.com/helloworld as the short URL to their new page.

No problem, I'll do a htaccess redirect on it, redirect the shorturl to the right page (which is ex.com/careers/helloworld-recruiting)

But theres a page on my site which is ex.com/services/helloworld, and for some reason, the htaccess redirect is bypassed in favor of the automatic wordpress URL recognition redirect.

So how can I ask Wordpress to kindly fuck off so I can use my own redirect instead of his?

Here's the line in my htaccess, tested with https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ it should go through as expected.

`RewriteRule ^helloworld/$ //careers/helloworld-recruiting/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop Wordpress from "guessing" redirects for nonexistent URLs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28045/stop-wordpress-from-guessing-redirects-for-nonexistent-urls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a WP-specific question, but I'll help you out. That regex will match `ex.com/helloworld/` but not `ex.com/helloworld`.

To handle both you'd want `RewriteRule ^helloworld/?$ /careers/helloworld-recruiting/ [L,R=301]`

The question mark makes the preceding token optional and the single slash rather than double in the rewritten URL makes it relative to the root.

Comment: Yeah, just figured out that was my bug. The good old one character away from working, but you have no idea why it doesn't work